# How exclude html comments from text node xpath?

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have the follow html structure:

```
<a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                text node 1<br>
                text node 2  <!--//comments-->
            </span>
        </div> 
    </div>
</a>
```

With the follow query, i get second node, but how get that node excluding comments?

```
$spanx = $xpath->query('//a/div/div/span/text()[2]');
$span = $spanx->item($l)->nodeValue;
echo "<td>".$span."</td></tr>";
```

I have that result:

```
text node 2 //comments
```

I search for:

```
text node 2
```

Comment: `$x("//span/text()[2]")[0].nodeValue.trim()` is fetching only `text node 2`.

Comment: @supputuri  how is that sintax in php?

Comment: @Emma filter result with regex is my last option, but xpath have `comment()` to get comments, so i try solution to deny or exclude comment... but thanks for tip...

Comment: If you use the `text()` node test you shouldn't get a comment node, unless there is some other relevant piece of code you had not showed us.

Comment: @Alejandro maybe u right couse i test the answer solution and the comments come yet, so o gona review my code and post other parts to comments. TKS.

Comment: @magichat please remember to award the bounty, otherwise only half of the bounty will be awarded and the other half will go to waste.  I am bothering to comment to you because on several occasions I've missed out on receiving full bounties because the OP went missing.  Thx.

Comment: @mickmackusa hello your solution don't work fo me, i check the code to see whats wrong, and i need test with your example  before bounty. TKS for try help.

Comment: Then I would appreciate if you would improve your question.   If you provide environment details or a more realistic string perhaps I can adjust my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested the following on my localhost.  I've created the file named `DOM_with_comment.html` containing:

```
<a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                text node 1<br>
                text node 2  <!--//comments-->
            </span>
        </div> 
    </div>
</a>
```

When I run:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('DOM_with_comment.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($xpath->query('//a/div/div/span/text()') as $item) {
    var_dump($item->nodeValue);
}
```

The output is:

```
string(29) "
                text node 1"
string(31) "
                text node 2  "
string(14) "
            "
```

---

So, by accessing the first qualifying result `[0]` from your xpath query then displaying the `trim()`ed `->nodeValue()` with `var_export()` it is revealed that there are no comments or whitespaces on either side of the targeted substring.

```
var_export(trim($xpath->query('//a/div/div/span/text()[2]')[0]->nodeValue));
// outputs: 'text node 2'
```

---

p.s. If your input is not coming from a file, but a variable, this works the same way:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                text node 1<br>
                text node 2  <!--//comments-->
            </span>
        </div> 
    </div>
</a>
HTML;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: @Magic can we consider this question resolved? If not, let me know what is wrong.